# Setting initial values for SQLite in onCreate() of SQLiteOpenHelper

Tags: android, performance, sqlite, sqliteopenhelper

I am creating an Android app for which I need to create a SQLite DB and pre-populate it with some values.

The Android documentation says this about what to do in "onCreate" of the SQLiteOpenHelper:

> Called when the database is created for the first time. This is where the creation of tables and the initial population of the tables should happen.

Reference - http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html#onCreate(android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase)

I am doubtful about the following 2 things -

- What is meant by "when database is created for the first time"? Is this done on the first launch of the app or only when the first DB request (read/write etc) is done.

  If it is the latter, I fear that it may take quite some time to create DB, pre-populate it with values (I have about 60 rows to be inserted into 1 table) and then read the DB to show it. Is this the best practice?
- I have been doing all my DB operations in AsyncTasks. But I am doing the table creations in onCreate using "db.execSQL" statements. Is this fine (in terms of convention/ performance) or should I go for an AsyncTask here as well?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: "What is meant by "when database is created for the first time"? Is this done on the first launch of the app or only when the first DB request (read/write etc) is done." -- it is when you call `getReadableDatabase()` or `getWriteableDatabase()` on the `SQLiteOpenHelper` and the database file does not already exist.

Comment: Okay.. but in that case, will that not affect the performance? Alternatively, should I ship the app with a pre-populated DB? It seems to be quite a tricky task and I would like to avoid it I think.

Comment: "will that not affect the performance?" -- well, you have to open the database *sometime*. 'Alternatively, should I ship the app with a pre-populated DB?" -- oh, if that's an option for your use case, I would definitely do that, [using `SQLiteAssetHelper`](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper). "It seems to be quite a tricky task and I would like to avoid it I think" -- it's not that tough, IMHO.

Comment: Thanks! Will try SQLiteAssetHelper

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is meant by "when database is created for the first time"? Is this done on the first launch of the app or only when the first DB request (read/write etc) is done.

- It happens when you first query from database in general term. After that only Upgrade method is called that too when you change the db version.

If it is the latter, I fear that it may take quite some time to create DB, pre-populate it with values (I have about 60 rows to be inserted into 1 table) and then read the DB to show it. Is this the best practice?

- 60 rows insertion is not a big task. More you can read about beginTransaction(),commitTransaction and endTransaction for insertion. It will make your insertion task lighting fast.

I have been doing all my DB operations in AsyncTasks. But I am doing the table creations in onCreate using "db.execSQL" statements. Is this fine (in terms of convention/ performance) or should I go for an AsyncTask here as well?

- It good you are doing you Db operation in AsyncTask and its completely fine.

Comment: Yes, I am doing the initial population of DB using beginTransaction(), setTransactionSuccessful() and endTransaction() in a try-finally bracket. How does this fare compared to AsyncTask (using cursors etc) in terms of performance?

Comment: Thanks for the "beginTransaction..." tip... markedly improved the speed!

Answer (score 1):

1) The later. It is done on the first read or write to the DB.

Your fear might be correct, this is why you can ship your app with a database that's already populated. Or you can launch an AsyncTask with a simple `SELECT 1 FROM anytable` query. More about shipping with DB [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513084/how-to-ship-an-android-application-with-a-database). (60 rows is nothing to fear about tho, and you can safely just keep using AsyncTasks).

2) Yes it is fine. The onCreate logic will run when you first read/write the DB, so it if you always use AsyncTasks onCreate will run in an AsyncTask also.

Answer (score 0):

### **Speaking of DB operations:**

Performing DB operations in `AsyncTask` is not a good approach, generally. As you might encounter a problem called "memory leak", and it might come as a silent assassin in the night.

There's lot written on this issue. Just google "asynctask leak context" and here you go.

### **So how to perform DB operations?**

Using `Loader API` in conjunction with `ContentProvider` is considered **good approach** for querying database. `Loader` asynchronously queries your database and delivers the result to specified subscribers. Configuration changes or other sudden stuff does not bother it.

And it is **really convenient** to query your data using loader API once you know how to do it.

Single inserts/updates/deletes might be done directly from the main thread via `ContentResolver`. These calls will be blocking (synchronous), but I bet you user would never notice anything while the amount of data is not large.

If you're operating on a large dataset, and you fear you'll be significantly blocking UI thread, I'd suggest using `IntentService` or any custom Service capable of doing operations in background (***note*** that by default `Service` operates on main UI thread and you have to specify background operation yourself or use `IntentService`)

### **Speaking of DB initialisation**:

You might create a one-time `IntentService`, if you're initialising a large set of data. It will handle your request asynchronously  and, for example, perform a broadcast that the application is set up and ready, so you might stop a *"wait a sec, performing app initialisation"* screen and show user your data.

There's also nothing wrong with shipping your database along with application, though it appears to be a bit hackish solution.

Either way, you choose what is more suitable for you.